# How to get the schema of the Dataframe as a string using spark-scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to dataframes and my question is there any way i could get the dataframe schema as a string in spark scala?

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").csv("sample_file1.txt")
df.show(truncate = false)
```

I have read the above dataframe and in the result section i'm getting the schema as:

```
Schema: code0, code1, date, hi, _c4, first_name, _c6, last_name1, _c8, _c9, _c10, _c11, _c12, _c13, _c14, _c15, _
c16, _c17, _c18, _c19, _c20, _c21, _c22, _c23, _c24
```

How will I be able to read this as a string as I need to validate this schema in spark SQL by passing this as a string..

Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation of a sample dataframe

```
val df = spark.range(1).selectExpr("'hello' as mystr","1 as myint","2.3 as mydec","current_date as mydt")
```

The solution

```
val cols = df.columns.mkString(",")
```

---

```
println(cols)
```

> mystr,myint,mydec,mydt

Comment: This works and i'm able to get the columns as string but unable to fit in a temporary view like " df.createOrReplaceTempView("cols") ". Is this the right approach? coz I want to use this string for validation in spark- SQL. Please share your point of view

Comment: We are discussing two things that have nothing to do with each other. `df.createOrReplaceTempView('myv')` enables you to use the dataframe as a table in  query, E g. `SQL('select * from myv')`

Comment: ohh ok.. can you please suggest on this...I need to read  a dataframe (26 columns) and i need to populate  the 26th column from the 'date' column(can be any where from 1 to 25). The catch is 26th field should be populated only if the column name is 'date'. can we do it using spark sql? and if so please share your views

Comment: Please open a new post for this, including at least couple of samples (you don't need to supply all 25 columns) and the desired result, although I have to say that this sounds like a bad practice for data engineering

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of columns as a string, David's answer will work.  If you want the actual schema as a string (for some reason):

```
val schemaAsString = yourDF.schema.toString
```